# Implicit differentiation with sin functions

Tags: calculus

I can't find an example in my book so I am not sure how I am suppose to do this.

I am trying to find the derivative of $y$ for $y+x\cos(y) = x^2y$

Comment: use chain rule.

Comment: So the xcosy is 1(cosy)+x(-siny)?

Comment: Close. Don't say "is," because you're not saying they're equal. And you are differentiating with respect to $x$, so the derivative of $\cos y$ - using the chain rule - is $(-\sin y)y'$. And that's just differentiating the left-hand side; now try what's on the right.

Comment: use the chain and product rules.

Comment: I got $y\prime + cosy(y\prime) - 2xy\prime y$

Comment: product rule: $(x \cos(y))'=x'\cos(y)+x(\cos(y))'$

Comment: product rule: $(x^2y)'=(x^2)'y+x^2y'$

Comment: I feel like there is a 2x missing from that.

Comment: are you thinking about $(x^2)'=2x$?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.

Comment: @Austin: That's fair, though the post by OP shows little to no research effort.  A simple google search brings up a good amount of information on the process.

Comment: That isn't really constructive since I did say I looked but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

When you do implicit differentiation problems, there are three important things to keep in mind.

1. Whenever you have a mixture of $x$ and $y$ factors, you must use the product/quotient rule.
2. Whenever you differentiate a term involving $y$, you must include a factor of $y^\prime$ (since we are differentiating with respect to $x$, not $y$).
3. If you did not differentiate a factor of $y$, you do not include a factor of $y^\prime$.

Keeping these things in mind, I get
$$
1 \cdot y^\prime + (\cos(y) - x\sin(y)y^\prime) = (2xy + x^2\cdot 1 \cdot y^\prime),
$$
where I've included parentheses to show where product rule is taking place.

Now, the whole point of this business was to get $y^\prime$ by itself. So, move everything having to do with $y^\prime$ to one side of the equation and all other terms to the other.
$$
y^\prime - x\sin(y)y^\prime - x^2y^\prime = 2xy - \cos(y).
$$
Factoring out the $y^\prime$ gives
$$
y^\prime(1 - x\sin(y) - x^2) = 2xy - \cos(y).
$$
Finally, dividing to isolate $y^\prime$ leaves us with
$$
y^\prime = \frac{2xy - \cos(y)}{1 - x\sin(y) - x^2}.
$$